# AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'tempdir'

Tags: python

I am working with macs2 which is a python-based tool. I used this command:

```
macs2 callpeak -t 866992_part.bam -c 866991_part.bam -f BAM --nomodel -g hs -n example -B -q 0.01 --outdir  peakCall
```

but gave this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'tempdir'
```

if I try this command:

```
macs2 callpeak -t 866992_part.bam -c 866991_part.bam -f BAM --nomodel -g hs -n example -B -q 0.01 --outdir  /peakCall
```

it will gives this error:

```
Output directory (/peakCall) could not be created. Terminating program.
```

do you know how I can resolve this problem?

Comment: Do your program has access to create directories in working directory?

Comment: it actually creates but empty and gives this error

Comment: You need to pass `--tempdir` to the command line.

Comment: then it gives this error macs2: error: unrecognized arguments: --tempdir /file